# PHP - reading from the end of a text file

Tags: php, arrays, text, file-io

I have a text file with values separated by a comma.

Example:

```
1299491735618,10,84,10,121.6,10,120.0,12994917389996,12, 13, 14, 15, and so on ..
```

Now, I need to read only the last "set" of data, i.e. only from `12994917389996,12, 13, 14, 15, and so on ...`

In this case, I guess `12994917389996` is greater than 130 and other values are less than 130. So, I need to read FROM `12994917389996` to the end of file...

Hope you got it!

EDIT 1:  No, It's a dynamic text file which keeps getting updated and I need to read only the last set of data every time !

EDIT 2 :  MY code

```
<?php
$file = fopen('graph.txt', 'r') or die("can't open file");

if ($file) {
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = trim(fgets($file));
        if (strlen($line)) {
            $fields = explode(",", $line);
            $num = count($fields);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
                $keyval[$i] = $fields[$i];
                if ($i == 0) {
                    $keyval['x'][] = $fields[$i];
                    echo $keyval['x'][0];
                }
                else {
                    if ($i % 2 == 0) $keyval['y'][] = $fields[$i];
                    else $keyval['y1'][] = $fields[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

HERE , I use $keyval[x][] to store the giant xxxxxxxxxxxxx values and keyval[y][] and keyval[y1][] to store ALTERNATING values AFTER That GIANT (xxxxxxxxxxxxx ) value .... This should clarify everything !

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not sure I get it... You want to get all numbers from the first number bigger than 130 except the first one? Man, that's complicated :D

How about this?

```
$str = "1299491735618,10,84,10,121.6,10,120.0,12994917389996,12,13,14,15,16,17";

$arr = explode(',', $str);

$i = 1;
while ($i < count($arr) && floatval($arr[$i]) < 130)
  $i++;

print_r(array_slice($arr, $i));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12994917389996
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 14
    [4] => 15
    [5] => 16
    [6] => 17
)
```

Comment: The point is I need to read from the END of the file ... not from the first !

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help.

```
$ echo '1299491735618,10,84,10,121.6,10,120.0,12994917389996,12, 13, 14, 15'  > file
$ php -a
php > $fp = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');
php > fseek($fp, 38);
php > echo fgets($fp);
12994917389996,12, 13, 14, 15
```

If not, could you be more specific about data structure stored in file?

Comment: Hi the file is just as I mentioned ...1299491735618,10,84,10,121.6,10,120.0 (and so on...) ,12994917389996,12, 13, 14, 15, and so on ..  I just need to read the last set of data !

Comment: Is your data structure well defined? I mean, can you state that you need last 30 bytes of file or this number may vary? Will it always be XXXXXXXXXX, XX, XX.X, XX, XX or your data structure may be different from this pattern? You can save some processor time and memory by not reading the whole file. In this case you simply open it, seek for the last 30 bytes, read and close your file (approach I've offered above). You can get filesize minus 30 bytes from the end and seek for this number (2nd fseek functions argument)

Comment: Youre right but THE file is dynamic and value keeps appending to it ... All I need is to read the last SET of data ... The only structure I can discern is that .. the xxxxxxxxxxx value is definitely greater than 130 and other values are less than 130.. si I need to read from the END of the file, TILL the value that is greater than 130 ... So, the output is like u've mentioned.. it needs to b dynamic

Comment: I have added my CODE, please suggest modifications ! Thanks