# What is the most efficient PHP way to read first and last line of a file?

Tags: php

I'm trying to open a file and determine if it is valid. It's valid if the first line is START and the last line is END.

I've seen different ways of getting the last line of a file, but it does not pay particular attention to the first line either.

How should I go about this? I was thinking of loading the file contents in an array and checking $array[0] and $array[x] for START and END. But this seems to be a waste for all the junk that could possibly be in the middle.

If its a valid file, I will be reading/processing the contents of the file between START and END.

Comment: use `fgets` to read the first line. for the last line see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025875/what-is-the-best-way-in-php-to-read-last-lines-from-a-file/15025877#15025877

Comment: Maybe useful: [6451232/reading-large-files-from-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451232/reading-large-files-from-end). Also see [File seek: See the examples for accessing files quickly from the end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php).

Answer (score 1):

Don't read entire file into an array if it is not needed. If file can be big you can do it that way:

```
$h = fopen('text.txt', 'r');
$firstLine = fgets($h);
fseek($h, -3, SEEK_END);
$lastThreeChars = fgets($h);
```

Memory footprint is much lower

Comment: wasent me but it is inefficient

Comment: fseek with SEEK_END is much better than iterate through all lines

Answer (score -1):

That's from me:

```
$lines = file($pathToFile);
if ($lines[0] == 'START' && end($lines) == 'END') {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: file reads the whole file into an array. If it more than ~50k lines   most default php setups will not support an array of that length.

Comment: @NickMaroulis does it in any way interferes with OP question?

Comment: it will work but the OP asked for an efficient method.

Comment: He asked for method for both first AND last line. And he haven't specified size of the file so I just pointed the simpliest way. If you have better make your own answer.

Comment: the OP suggested this method himself, so its not much help as an answer

Answer (score -1):

Reading whole file with fgets will be efficient for small siles. iF ur file is big then:

1. open It and read first line
2. use tail (i didn't check it but it looks OK)  function I found in php.net in fseek documentation