# Reading and Limiting Apache Log File

Tags: php, apache, fopen

I'm trying to create a parsing script for the Apache access.log file that will ultimately give output as a graph but right now I need to limit the result to only the last 50 rows which I have done but it needs to also limit by site (I have many on my server) and show only distinct visitors. I mainly want to know where visitors came from, not what they did once they got there.

The code below is reverse sorting and pulling up a limited number of entries. However, it is not yet limiting by site or by distinct visitor but otherwise it is creating the file. The parsing portion has not yet been finalized so it is not outputting anything when run in the browser but neither is it giving any errors.

```php
<?php

$log_path = (getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') == "127.0.0.1") ? "C:/Server/Apache/logs" : "/usr/local/apache/logs";
$LogFile = "$log_path/access.log";
$TmpFile = "$log_path/logreversed.txt";

function LimitSize($path, $tmp, $line_count, $block_size) {
    $lines = array();
    $fh = fopen($path, 'r');
    fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_END);
    do {
        $can_read = $block_size;
        if( ftell($fh) < $block_size) :
            $can_read = ftell($fh);
        endif;

        fseek($fh, -$can_read, SEEK_CUR);
        $data = fread($fh, $can_read);
        fseek($fh, -$can_read, SEEK_CUR);

        $split_data = array_reverse(explode("\n", $data));
        $new_lines = array_slice($split_data, 0, -1);
        $lines = array_merge($lines, $new_lines);
    }
    while (count($lines) < $line_count && ftell($fh) != 0);
    fclose($fh);
    $output = array_slice($lines, 1, $line_count);
    $text = "";
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) :
        $text .= $key." : ".$value."\n";
    endforeach;
    $fh = fopen($tmp, "w") or die("Could not open tmp file.");
    fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write file!");
    fclose($fh);
}

LimitSize($LogFile, $TmpFile, 50, 16384);

$pattern = '/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (\[[^\]]+\]) "(.*) (.*) (.*)" ([0-9\-]+)
    ([0-9\-]+) "(.*)" "(.*)"$/';

if (is_readable($TmpFile)) :
    $fh = fopen($TmpFile,'r') or die($php_errormsg);
    $requests = array();
    $i = 1;
    while (!feof($fh)) :
        if ($s = trim(fgets($fh,16384))) :
            if (preg_match($pattern,$s,$matches)) :
                list($whole_match,$remote_host,$logname,$user,$time,
                     $method,$request,$protocol,$status,$bytes,$referer,
                     $user_agent) = $matches;
                $requests[$request]++;
            else :
                error_log("Can't parse line $i: $s");
            endif;
        endif;
    endwhile;
    fclose($fh) or die($php_errormsg);

    foreach ($requests as $request => $accesses) :
        printf("%6d   %s\n",$accesses,$request);
    endforeach;

else : 
    echo "cannot access log file!";
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading large files from end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451232/reading-large-files-from-end)

Answer (score -1):

cd /etc/logrotate.d/;
echo "/var/log/httpd/* /etc/httpd/logs/* {
    daily 
    maxage 1
    rotate 1
    size 1M
    missingok
    notifempty 
    sharedscripts 
    compress 
    delaycompress 
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true 
    endscript 
}"  > httpd;